# Can modules for different providers be defined in the same hierarchy in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm working on refactoring our Terraform scripts to reduce duplication, and to take advantage of the new conditional module syntax in 0.13. We support 2 different deployment platforms, Docker and Openshift, so we currently have 2 sets of modules, for roughly 60 services, so we end up with ~120 .tf files.

I'm trying to consolidate down to a single .tf file for each service, with the Docker and Kubernetes/Openshift modules in the same file. We've got scripts that inject the main driver for each provider at run time. Everything was working great with only the Docker modules, but now that I've added the Kubernetes/Openshift modules, I'm having an issue.

Trying to run any commands (validate/plan/apply) is processing both sets of modules, and because of their differing structure, it's failing. I've got the conditional on the module, checking the input variable for the deployment platform, but I believe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the way the conditionals are handled, as it seems to happen at run time vs at plan time. For example, running a Docker deployment now fails due to missing resources in the Kubernetes/Openshift modules, and vice versa.

Can the modules be constructed in this way, or will we just have to have 2 separate sets of files?

Docker driver:

```
/**
* # Docker Driver
* Configures docker provider for use in Docker deployment environments.
*/
provider "docker" {
  host = var.docker_host
  dynamic registry_auth {
    for_each = var.docker_deployment_type == "online" ? [
      1] : []
    content {
      address = var._image_registry
      config_file = pathexpand(var.docker_config_path)
    }
  }
}

resource "docker_network" "project" {
  name = var.docker_network
  driver = "bridge"
  check_duplicate = true
  ipam_config {
    subnet = var.docker_network_subnet
    gateway = var.docker_network_gateway
  }
}

output "docker-network" {
  value = docker_network.project.name
}
```

Kubernetes/Openshift driver:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "${var.openshift_host}:${var.openshift_port}"
}

resource "random_string" "instance_identifier" {
  count = var.deployment_target == "openshift" ? 1 : 0
  length = 6
  special = false
  lower = true
  upper = false
  number = true
}

module "service-image-pull-credentials" {
  source = "./modules/openshift/generic-terraform-modules/secret"
  count = var.deployment_target == "openshift" ? 1 : 0
  secret_name = "service-image-pull-credentials-${random_string.instance_identifier[0].result}"
  openshift_project = var.openshift_project
  instance_identifier = random_string.instance_identifier[0].result
  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = jsonencode({
      "auths" : {
        "project-address.nexus.abc" : {
          email = file(var.image_pull_email_file)
          username = file(var.image_pull_username_file)
          password = file(var.image_pull_password_file)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
}

module "service-credentials" {
  source = "./modules/openshift/generic-terraform-modules/secret"
  count = var.deployment_target == "openshift" ? 1 : 0
  secret_name = "service-credentials-${random_string.instance_identifier[0].result}"
  openshift_project = var.openshift_project
  instance_identifier = random_string.instance_identifier[0].result
  data = {
    username = file(var.service_account_username_file)
    password = file(var.service_account_password_file)
    email = file(var.service_account_email_file)
  }
}
```

Example module file:

```
module "service-docker" {
  source = "./modules/docker/generic-java"
  count = var.deployment_target == "docker" ? 1 : 0
  docker_tag = var.service_docker-tag
  image_registry = var.image_registry
  keep_locally = var.docker_keep_locally
  network = docker_network.project.name
  deployment_type = var.docker_deployment_type
  ...
}

module "service-openshift" {
  source = "./modules/openshift/generic-spring-java"
  count = var.deployment_target == "openshift" ? 1 : 0
  image_pull_credentials = module.service-image-pull-credentials[0].secret.metadata[0].name
  instance_identifier =random_string.instance_identifier[0].result
  openshift_project = var.openshift_project
  image_tag = var.service_docker-tag
  image_namespace = var.image_namespace
  image_registry = var.image_registry
  image_name = var.service_image-name
  ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a `for` expression instead of the older `count` design pattern for this?

Comment: Just tried it, same issue :/